# Why is Instagram Embed not showing on my react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to embed an instagram feed on my react app. But for some reason the embeded post doesn't show up on the app.
I imported as I was supposed to with
`import InstagramEmbed from 'react-instagram-embed';`
and used it as

```
<InstagramEmbed
          url='https://instagr.am/p/Zw9o4/'
          clientAccessToken='123|456'
          maxWidth={320}
          hideCaption={false}
          containerTagName='div'
          protocol=''
          injectScript
          onLoading={() => {}}
          onSuccess={() => {}}
          onAfterRender={() => {}}
          onFailure={() => {}}
      />
```

Maybe this has to do with the clientAccessToken?

Comment: did you fill in the clientAccessToken? the npm package says where to refer to fill that field: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/oembed/#access-tokens

Comment: How can I find the tokens?

Comment: To get a Client Access Token, sign into your App Dashboard and navigate to Settings > Advanced > Security > Client Token.